# Delete multiple entries with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm able to delete one entry at a time using AJAX. Now I've made the possibility to select entries using a checkbox and delete them all simultaneously, this works great without AJAX. Now I'm trying to delete multiple entries using AJAX. This is what I have so far:

the ajax:

```
`$(function() {
$(".checkbox_button_del").click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this).parents('tr:first');

                        var notice = '<div class="notice">'
                                  + '<div class="notice-body">' 
                                      + '<img src="core/displays/notify/delete-icon.png" alt="" />'
                                      + '<h3>Deleted item</h3>'
                                      + '<p>The item has been succesfully deleted.</p>'
                                  + '</div>'
                                  + '<div class="notice-bottom">'
                                  + '</div>'
                              + '</div>';

                        $ny( notice ).purr(
                            {
                                usingTransparentPNG: true
                            }
                        );
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "core/actions/delete_multiple.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function()
{
parent.fadeOut('300', function() {$(this).remove();});
    $("#load_tasklist").load("core/statistics/stats_brackets.php")
    $("#load_tweets").load("response.php")
    $("#load_mod_day_summary").load("core/displays/mod_day_summary.php")
    $("#load_mod_task_selector").load("core/displays/mod_task_selector.php")
}
});

return false;
});
});`
```

the external deleting script:`

```
include('../../core/additional/connect-db.php');

    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["chkDel"]);$i++)
    {
        if($_POST["chkDel"][$i] != "")
        {
            $strSQL = "DELETE FROM players ";
            $strSQL .="WHERE id = '".$_POST["chkDel"][$i]."' ";
            $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        }
    }



    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`
```

and the result list with the delete button: `

```
<form name="frmMain" id="myForm" method="post" OnSubmit="return onDelete();">


<?php 

 $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass)  or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
 mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE (userid = '$username' AND done = '0' AND measure = 'task' AND day = '$user_mydate') ORDER BY id DESC")
                    or die(mysql_error());

     echo '<div id="checkbox_button_div">
    <input class="checkbox_button_del" type="submit" id="buttondel" value="Delete" />
    <input class="checkbox_button_done" type="submit" id="buttondone" value="Done" />
    <input class="checkbox_button_done" type="submit" id="buttonfavorite" value="Favorite" />
    <input class="checkbox_button_done" type="submit" id="buttonmove" value="+1 day" />
    </div>';

     echo '

            <table id="tableOne" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="760" border="0" class="yui">    
        <thead>

            <tr>                                    

                <th><a href="#" title="Click Header to Sort">Task</a></th>

                <th><a href="#" title="Click Header to Sort">Minutes</a></th>
                <th><a href="#" title="Click Header to Sort">Time</a></th>

                <th><a href="#" title="Click Header to Sort">Category</a></th>
                <th> <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="check all" /></th>

            </tr>

        </thead>
     <tbody> ';    

        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {   
        $i++;
            include ('core/additional/params_tasks.php');

            echo ' 

            <tr class="handcursor" onmouseover="' .($mouseover). '" onmouseout="' .($mouseout). '">         

                <td class="editable" id="' .($id). '" width="180">' .($task). ' </td>
                <td class="editable" id="' .($id). '">' .($minutes). '</td>
                <td onClick="' .($onclick). '">' .($hours_start). '.' .($minutes_start). ' - ' .($hours_due2). '.' .($minutes_due2). ' </td>
                <td onClick="' .($onclick). '">' .($categorie). ' </td>         
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" name="chkDel[]" id="chkDel<?=$i;?>" value="' .($id). '"></td>

            </tr> ';

            }
            // close table>
            echo '</tbody>
        <tfoot>
                <tr style="display:none;">
                <td style="border: 0px;" colspan="4">
                    No matching results..
                </td>
            </tr>           
        </tfoot>
     </table>

      '; 

     ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="hdnCount" value="<?=$i;?>">

    </form>`
```

I think the AJAX script should pass the "$i" values as well, but I don't know how to do this. Please tell me if the problem isn't clear to you. Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: Does FireBug give you any errors?

Comment: the problem isn't clear, what's the question?

Comment: Hello, the AJAX is being executed (and gives a success message) but nothing is being deleted. My question is: how should I modify the AJAX script so it passes the right form information? Thanks :)

Comment: Why dont you create an array of ID's from the check boxes. pass that to your script, and delete records using - delete from table where id in(....) ? It should be simple enough.

Comment: sound like a good solution, pity enough I'm not skilled enough yet to write this on my own, can you help me out (if this doesn't consume too much time) ?:)

Comment: Sorry, didnt check this for a while. have posted a solution . Comment if problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yout jquery would be somthing like this.

```
$("#Submit1").click(function () {

            var arr = new Array();


            $("input:checked").each(function () {

                arr.push($(this).attr("id"));

            }); //each

            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
       url: "core/actions/delete_multiple.php",
       data: arr ,//pass the array to the ajax call
       cache: false,

       success: function()
             {   }
       });//ajax

            }); //each


        }); //click
```

since the PHP function will get a JSON object. you will need to do a JSON decode to ge the array.... see [JSON decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)... use this array to create your query like..

```
   delete from SalesLT.Customer
where CustomerID in (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: couldn't get it to work :( need some help with the json (docu pages are offline btw) can you rewrite the delete_multiple.php file for me? (only if it costs u a few minutes!) thanks in advance